# List of Camel DSL commands

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

I am working on camel and new to that technology as well. i pretty much understand the concepts, but i couldnt find a place where I can get the list of DSL commands(both JAVA & Spring) and their functionalities.
Also is it possible to create user defined DSL that we can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [EIP](https://camel.apache.org/eip) page. Basically, most Camel DSLs are implementation of the EIP.